# Error Codes with Properties Files or Database

Tags: api-design, error-handling, errors

I'm about to implement Error codes for my company API, so, based on rfc7807 I will include a type which is an error type which is basically an error category, and inside those categories we have a bunch of error codes, so, I'm stuck thinking/searching what's the best approach to follow, I mean, if i handle these error categories/codes in database, I'll need to define an enum with the codes to lookup in database their descriptions..

So this doesn't sound maintainable, because although the codes are in DB and it doesn't depends on the application server to deploy, everytime i define an error code or category in database i'll need to define it in the enum which sucks.

but seems like there's no other way to handle it, thing is, i need this error handling to work in several distributed units (microservices, some monoliths, etc) so what could be a good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

**Error Code != Enum**

Your Error Code is not an enumeration, it is its own object.

Enumeration (and constants in general) are great ways to encode the initialisation value of an Error Code.

They are horrible as the storage unit itself. Because as you point out a receiver defining the error code as an enumeration dictates what are "legal" error codes, even though it has the least information about it.

**Identity, Category, and Semantics**

So what do you mean when you say *Error Code*?

- Is it a unique identifier that describes one very specific failure state?
- Is it a categorical identifier that describes a class of failures?
- Is it an instruction that describes how the receiver of the error should respond?
- Or some combination of the above?

The only place that knows the error code, is the place that generates it. (Hopefully corroborated by judicious unit tests.)

Everywhere else, be it in the same application or afar, does not care about the exact value. What they care about are capabilities (serialisation) and questions (network issue?, can I try again?).

**Distribution**

The other issue you have hit upon is that you are distributing the same responsibility across several actors.

This is no different to any other kind of message passed between systems. I recommend defining the protocol of each interface. Each system that works through that interface has to map to and from that protocol in whatever way makes sense.

This is painful, but they are separate pieces of software. Increasing the coupling between them by forcing a shared notion of error code (aside from what is defined in the interface protocol between them) makes both pieces of software more brittle.

Brittle - not just because they must use the same version of the library - but because they must synchronise appropriate uses of unique identifying error codes, and fully agreeing to the categories and semantics of error codes in general.

You could ameliorate the brittleness by insisting on backward compatibility, but that is its own cage of snakes.

Comment: Actually I'm not following you, I mean, I didn't say I was going to use an Enumeration as the source of the error codes, I said, I was going to store them in database, and I was going to use an Enumeration to put the error keys so i can get the category, descripton etc from the database...

Comment: @Ricardo okay, that wasn't quite clear from your question. You mention multiple services for which this is to work across, and that there is a DB and an enum - no mention of an error object or class. Perhaps you should consider writing a script to auto generate the file containing the enum. eg: build the db, run the extract script and replace the enum containing file, then compile the binary.

Answer (score 0):

So the main worry is maintainability of database list and a plethora of software systems.

The first errors should be **hierarchical**:

- (Any)
- SQL
- SQL-Syntax
- SQL-Constraint
- SQL-Constraint-Unique

So the two components with different DB versions, can still give an undefined error with its upper category.

This might also mean adding a **version** to every error, and the overall database. And hold a version in the software of the DB used.

Now something technical. A language level enumeration (like java `enum`) is a *closed* domain of values. Adding new values does not really fit. It is means having a global class (**enum or error class**) used from many different modules.

Having a single point for adding, one could **(re-)generate** the enum from the database.
Best with a small tool integrated in the build with a sorted enum output and version number increase. Database table to code or vice versa: code (data) to database.

In general I would create a **separate library** so different dependency versions can be kept in parallel.

*All this will come as no surprise, but your question - whether there is a neater solution -, unfortunately has no real solution AFAIK. You might consider workflows/pipelines going in one specific direction, like generating from an enum a database table, generating from the database a Software Design Report on Errors.*